# http cookie not getting set on browser openam

Tags: openam

I am trying to generate a http cookie for succesfull user login in openam.
The cookie is expected to be populated with a ldap attribute name 'commerce' which is a boolean attribute.

In order to achieve this I have done settings under --
access control --top level realm --agent -- configured policy agent --Profile Attributes Processing

Over here I have created a map with key as commerce and value of commerce, now ideally after a succesfull login it should generate a cookie with name --HTTP_COMMERCE with value of attribute, but this is not working as expected.

Can some one help me out in resolving what I may be missing over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Profile Attributes Processing it is probably important to know that the attributes are retrieved from the configured data stores, hence you should probably make sure that the data store has correctly configured in OpenAM.

Most likely you are just missing the "commerce" attribute from the "LDAP User Attributes" setting.